# How do I calculate and fill out a companion sheet for Ranger in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions, character-sheets

I'm new to D&D.  A friend helped me with my Character Sheet but now I need help with my Companion Sheet. They had never made one so couldn't help.

We're using the new *[UA revised ranger](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf)* and I'm going to be starting at level 4 with my pet: I chose Giant Badger from the list.  I've tried to look up guides but they are from other past versions or incomplete.  I find any other sources to help me with this problem.

This is the type of Companion Sheet I have:

[image: D&D 5e companion sheet]

Comment: Where'd you get this companion sheet?

Comment: @BlueMoon93 Um , I think it was on a reddit forum or some other forum? The creator revised it over and over through player feedback. If I can find the link, I'll post it.

Comment: Link to the sheet. The only problem I found is it doesn't have a box for Proficiency Bonus, but I made due and wrote it in that blank area between Str and Death Saves.
https://www.reddit.com/r/DnD/comments/4h19ll/5e_final_fillable_companion_sheet/

Answer (score 7):

## Start with the Giant Badger stats, then apply Companion's Bond effects.

Read through the Animal Companion and Companion's Bond section of the [UA revised ranger rules](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_RevisedRanger.pdf). Look at the Giant Badger stats from the Monster Manual (p. 32), [SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf), or [D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com).

The changes to your badger would be:

1. **Remove its Multiattack action.** There's a sidebar in the UA ranger rules that explains why.
2. **Use your proficiency bonus instead of its own.** Since you are 4th level, your proficiency bonus is +2, but that's what the Giant Badger's bonus is as well. See below for how to figure this out (it isn't obvious!)
3. **Add its proficiency bonus to AC and damage rolls.** So you would add +2 to the base giant badger AC of 10, and add +2 damage to any attacks it can make (in addition to other bonuses).
4. **Choose two skills for your badger to be proficient in.**
5. **Your badger is proficient in all saving throws,** so apply its proficiency bonus to all of its saving throw bonuses. Since a giant badger is not normally proficient in *any* saving throws, this just means adding +2 to all its saves.
6. **Add hit dice**. Since you one level above 3rd, your badger gets an additional hit die. A giant badger normally has two 8-sided hit dice, so roll another d8 and add that many hit points, +2 for the badger's Constitution bonus, to the badger's base hit points of 13. Your DM may allow you to replace the d8 roll with a fixed 5 hit points, just as player characters with d8 hit dice can; you would still add the +2 Constitution bonus in this case.
7. **Improve ability scores.** Since you have gained the Ability Score Improvement class feature once, you may increase two of the badger's ability scores by 1, or one of them by 2. Be sure to update the badger's attack bonuses, damage, hit points, and armor class if these improvement increase its Strength, Constitution or Dexterity bonuses.
8. **Add a personality trait and flaw.** You can roll these on the provided tables, or make up your own.

Whenever you gain a level, you will need to update the badger's stats as well, adding an additional hit die each level, and possibly changing its proficiency bonus and improving ability scores. Your companion will also gain other abilities when you reach 5th, 7th, 11th and 15th level as a ranger.

---

How can you figure out a creature's proficiency bonus? There are two ways. The first is to look at its Challenge Rating (CR). This is sort of like a character's level, and a creature has a proficiency bonus as if it were a character of the same level as its CR, or a 1st-level character if the creature's CR is less than 1. A giant badger is CR 1/4, so it has the same proficiency bonus as a 1st-level character, or +2.

The other way is to look at the creature's stats and work backwards. A giant badger has a Strength bonus of +1, but its attack bonus is +3. From that you can deduce that its proficiency bonus must be +2, since the badger will be proficient with its attacks.

Comment: This is really helpful. I have some questions but I'm at work right now. I'll get back to you soon!

Comment: Okay, I'm home. The confusion that we've been having in making this is mostly the Hit Points. The 2d8 on all the sites we looked up for 'Giant Badger' said that it was 2d8+4. The DM for our campaign (He's newer to DMing and hasn't dealt with companions) said that my Badger would end up having way more health than me as we leveled and wanted to change it. Also, your saying that it would be 2d8+2 which is different.

Comment: The badger has d8 hit dice, and starts with two of them. With a Constitution of 15, it adds +2 hit points *per hit die*. So initially it has 2d8+4 hit points, and each hit die it gains is another 1d8 +2, just like for a player character. If you're 4th level and the badger has a Con of 15, it has 3d8+6 HP. Even if the badger does end up having more hit points than you, remember that its armor class is fairly low, so it will be taking damage much more often.

Comment: oh... So it's supposed to end up with higher hit points by end game? Like a tank sorta character?

Comment: I think the companion is supposed to be a viable combatant at all levels, but not overpowered. Also I would expect a ranger of level *N* to have more hit points than their giant badger companion -- the ranger has *N* d10 hit dice; the badger has *N-1* d8 hit dice.

Comment: Also, comments aren't for extended discussion; let me know if there are clarifications I can add to my answer, or you can ask a follow-up question.

Comment: But if it gets plus 2  added on each level.. Would that make it climb really quick? My constitution is only +3 to my 1d10

Comment: You also add your Constitution bonus each level. If you have a Con of 16, you gain 1d10+3 HP per level.

Comment: Okay, would it be easier to pm? Stackexchange is nice to find knowledgeable people but personally I feel the rules are a bit a strict to those in need of help  I have a lot of questions and no one around me is super into dnd, all Noobs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59864/discussion-between-marq-and-hush564).